Can someone share a comprehensive website to discuss identifying, choosing, prepping and cooking heirloom squash and pumpkins?
I realize Stack Exchange can't be the type of forum that could be used for users to start a discussion about this subject that isn't well understood by the target audience:  Heirloom Pumpkins and Squash Varieties - Flavor Profiles with Prep Tips.
Once the discussion is started, I'd guess there will be hundreds of questions and answers.  Of course, this is impossible until enough are interested and at least somewhat knowledgeable.

Squash is one of my favorite vegetables in winter, and I love a number of them.  Acorn, Butternut, Buttercup are favorites with great flavor of course, each with their own unique prep, cooking, and best practices. Aldi used to sell all their squash at an "each" price of about $1, vs by the pound today.  It was a great deal, and I'd often come home with 20-40 lbs to cook up and freeze.  Today however, a +$1.00 / Lb, not a great deal.
But now, I'm tempted to go a different route.  Why pay +1.00 / lb when I can buy a 30 Lb squash for $5-7, or under $0.30 / lb?  How??
Even in Florida, now there are a number of "heirloom pumpkin" providers that sell huge pallets of huge "pumpkins" and squash that I don't recognize.  Each are 10-50 Lbs and cost $5-7. They are "squash", and many seem to be great for cooking, but they have huge variations on flavor and prep.  There are few great guides, even from their providers.
For those of us that cook, making a mistake with a 30 lb squash would just quash my desire to keep experimenting.  So, either here or on another site, let's try to nail down at least a few varieties that are "huge bargains", with "huge great flavor profiles".  We know that the traditional decorative pumpkins are a huge disappointment, watery, with little to no flavor.
Example tips:
Acorn Squash -- You'll find lots of great recipes, but let's just deal with how to easily get the meat out, after gutting the seeds, without a lot of work or ending up with those very large inedible threads.  I've tried to cut them up into each of the raised sections, like sectioning a grapefruit.  But then you have to find and cut out the cord that evidently is so tough, that the cord restricts growth, which is how they end up with that acorn shape, instead of just round.  After sectioning, There is one tough cord for each indent.  Next, there are the ends, both at the tip and at the stem end.  These too are very tough, and so cut them off, usually about 1/2" on each end.  Next, I have to try to cut that cord out, which is hard to see, and easy to miss.
I then try to "peel" them, using either my great 8" chefs knife, or a veg peeler.  Both methods are difficult and time consuming.  As a result, I seldom buy these acorns, since they are just too much trouble.  Or, I simply follow the common method of cutting in half, gutting the seeds et al, filling or prepping, and then roasting. Of course, then you still have to try to eat while avoiding the skin and that cord in each section. Nah, even with it's unique and great flavor, I'll use the other varieties of butternut or buttercup.
I still want to find a great guide to help sort out which "giant pumpkins" will be great to cook with.  Today I have a "nice 22 Lb" turban-like squash I'm going to try to "process".  I'm tempted to either drop it from about a foot or so up, or get my machete that I use to cut brush, just to get started.  I'll likely try my chefs very thin tapered blade and see If I can cut a "pie shaped" piece out and cook that.  I'll get a decent picture of it before I do.
Here's one guide, with has a lot of pics and a few descriptions.  I'd like a lot more detail though for each.  I'd also like to just concentrate on the huge kind being sold:  https://www.liveeatlearn.com/types-of-squash/   Any tips, guides, or other website links would be great.  (I know that in the S.E. format, there's no specific "question" and no specific "answer" per se, but I'll try to use this forum first.  If that doesn't work, I'll add or create content elsewhere, and invite your help, advice, and contributions.)

Actually, this forum is designed for specific questions that lead to specific answers.    It would be helpful if you remove all of the extraneous information and specify your question.  For example, "Can someone share a comprehensive guide for identifying, choosing, and cooking heirloom squash?"  or "How does one choose an heirloom squash for cooking?"   Please keep it to one question, but feel free to create a new post with a new question.

Most of the pumpkins that are grown for size or longevity for jack-o-lanterns aren't particularly flavorful.  And make sure to clean you machete very well... the oils from poison ivy can stay on there for quite some time

moscafj  -- Thanks for trying to help.  Your reformed question seemed to me to not only be acceptable, but specific, asking only for a different website entirely--a site that can accept new (and existing) user's contributions without learning the nuances of the platform.  I'd forgotten why years ago I stopped contributing on anything related to any Stack Exchange forums.  I spent considerable time trying to shoehorn my inputs into this restricted format. -- Sorry, not worth the effort anymore.
